# updating JS script from 1.4.3 to 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JS script which uses jquery 1.4.3 to create and remove input text elements dynamically
I need to start using jquery 1.9.1

from what I can see the

```
       .live()
```

function need to change to

```
      .on()
```

but then only have half of the functionality works.. the Remove feature no longer works can anybody see why?

full source is at the jsfiddle link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/

```
    $(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
      });
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change a little the code, like this:

```
$(document).on('click','#remScnt', function () {
    ...
});
```

instead of

```
$('#remScnt').live('click', function () {
    ...
});
```

Like this, any time a `#remScnt` is added to the dom the click handler will be bound to the element.

Also, you should use `class` instead of `id` if you'll have more than one `remScnt` element in the page, the `id` should be unique.

**fiddle here:** http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/7313/